# How to display action bar list?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to display action bar and when user clicks on list icon (right side of the iamge) display my own list like main menu , discussion etc.( action overflow.)

#### It seems on one is here who can explain me how to do this my minsdkVersion is 16

[image]

Comment: please see follwing tut http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/

Comment: @andru first how to put image instead of link in stackoverflow?

Comment: When you are posting your question you will able to see a option for image uploading on the top bar of editor. Once you will have enough reputation you can upload image.

Comment: ok thanks now can you please tell me how to implement  action overflow.??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the following link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html

You can create custom Popup menu.

Comment: i want like above image

Comment: yes it will do your task.... i gave you the idea. now implement it like the way you want.